# $\{(n, \frac{1}{n}) : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ in the subspace topology of $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{Q}$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology

Consider $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{Q}$ as a subspace topology of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with usual topology. Consider the set $A = \{(n,\frac{1}{n}) : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$.
**Is $A$ closed, open ? What is the boundary of $A$ in $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{Q}$?**

*My Attempt:*

The basic open sets on $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{Q}$ will be of the form $n \times (a,b)\cap \mathbb{Q}$ where $(a,b)$ is open on $\mathbb{R}$.

So for a fixed $n$, $\{(n, \frac{1}{n})\}$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{Q}$. $A$ is a countable union if closed set.

To be open for any point $a \in A$ we shall get a basic open set $B$ s.t. $a \in B \subset A$. It does not hold. So $A$ is not open set.

$\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{Q} - A = \cup_n [n \times ((-\infty, \infty) - \frac{1}{n}) \cap \mathbb{Q}]$ is a countable union of open sets  $n \times ((-\infty, \infty) - \frac{1}{n}) \cap \mathbb{Q}$. So $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{Q} -A$ is an open set and so $A$ is a closed set.

The boundary of $A$ is empty.

Is my attempt correct? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'll throw in a hint for the closure part which might be valuable for gaining intuition.  $A$ is closed because every point is isolated -- for each point $x$, there is a neighborhood of $x$ which does not contain other points of $A$.  In particular, the ball of radius $1$ centered at $x$ does not contain any more points of $A$.  Prove that.  Similarly, $\partial A = A$ because every point is isolated, and every isolated point of a set is in its boundary.  Prove that too.

Comment: @nomen Just because every point of $A$ is isolated does not mean that $A$ is closed. Consider $A=\{ (0, \frac{1}{n})\ |\ n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{Q}$ as in the question. Then $A$ is not closed since $(0, 0) \not\in A$ and every neighbourhood of $(0,0)$ intersects $A$. But every point of $A$ has a neighbourhood that contains only that point. It is also not in general true that every isolated point of a set is in its boundary (consider a discrete topology on a set). This is true though for nice enough spaces.

Comment: @AlešBizjak So here $A$ is neither open nor closed. Is it?

Comment: @HopelessFool  Yes, it is neither.

Comment: @AlešBizjak: good catch, my mistake.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that the set $A$ is closed and not open, by the arguments you describe.

The boundary of $A$ however is not empty.

The boundary of $A$ is equal to $\text{Cl}(A) \setminus \text{Int}(A)$. Since $A$ is closed $\text{Cl}(A) = A$ but since it is not open $\text{Int}(A) \neq A$, so the boundary is not empty.

As you hint in your attempt, no point in $A$ has a basic open neighborhood in $A$, so the interior of $A$ is empty. Therefore the boundary of $A$ is $A$.

Comment: Thank you . Nice to learn.